# Having difficulty in a understanding regex backtracking

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I was browsing through the regex tagged questions on SO when i came accross this problem,

A regex for a url was needed, the url begins with domain.com/advertorials/

The regex should match the following scenarios,

> - domain.com/advertorials
> - domain.com/advertorials?test=true
> - domain.com/advertorials/
> - domain.com/advertorials/?test=true
>
>   but not this,
> - domain.com/advertorials/version1?test=true

I came up with this regex `advertorials\/?(?:(?!version)(.*))`

This should work, but it doesnt for the last case. Looking at the debugger in regex101.com,
i see that after matching 's/' it matches 'version' word character by character and  ultimately matches but since this is negative lookahead the condition fails. And this is the part i dont understand after failing it backtracks to before the '/' in 's/' and not after 's/'.

Is this how its supposed to work?? Can anyone help me understand?
(here's the demo link: https://regex101.com/r/ww3HR8/1).

Thanks,

Note:  People already gave their solutions on that problem i just want to know why my regex fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backtracking mechanism is in charge of this phenomenon, as you have already pointed out.

The `?` quantifier, matching 1 or 0 repetitions of the quantified subpattern lets the regex engine match the string in two ways: either matching the quantified subpattern, or go on matching the string with subsequent subpattern.

So, `advertorials/?(?!version)(.*)` (I removed the redundant `(?:...)` non-capturing group), when applied to `domain.com/advertorials/version1?test=true`, matches `advertorials`, then matches `/`, and then the negative lookahead checks if, immediately to the right of the current position, there is `version` substring. Since there is `version` after `/`, the regex engine goes back and sees that `/?` pattern can match an empty string. So, the lookahead check is re-applied striaght after `advertorials`. There is no `version` after `advertorials`, and the match is returned.

The usual solution is using possessive quantifiers or atomic groups, but there are other approaches, too.

E.g.

```
advertorials\/?+(?!version)(.*)
              ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ww3HR8/2). Here, `\/?+` matches 1 or 0 `/` chars, but once it matches, the egine cannot go back and re-match a part of a string with this pattern.

Or, you may include the `/?` in the lookahead and place it before `/?` pattern:

```
advertorials(?!\/?version)\/?(.*)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ww3HR8/3).

If you plan to disallow `version` anywhere after `advertorials` use

```
advertorials(?!.*version)\/?(.*)
```

See [yet another demo](https://regex101.com/r/ww3HR8/4).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Making the slash optional means there is a way to match without violating the constraint. If there is a way to match, the regex engine will find it, always.

Make the slash non-optional when it's followed by anything at all.

```
advertorials(?:/(?!version).*)?$
```

Incidentally, regex itself doesn't require the slash to be backslash-escaped (though some host languages use slashes as regex delimiters, so maybe you need to put it back). I also removed some redundant parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The reason:

This highlighted part is optional 
advertorials`\/?`(?:(?!version)(.*))

Therefore it can also be `advertorials(?:(?!version)(.*))`
which matches `advertorials/version`

Essentially, `(?!version)(.*)` matches `/version`

Btw, this is normal backtracking by 1 character.
If you have already fixed it, then we're done !